# Which portals do you recommend for the latest programming technology

Tags: portal

For my area, I get the updates from

- ww.asp.net
- code.google.com
- www.webmasterworld.com

What others do you highly recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're into anything with Linux:
http://www.linux.com/feature

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) has some excellent web articles

If you want keep up with browsers, [Web Browsers News and Reviews](http://www.favbrowser.com/) might help.

Finally, [PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/elsewhere/), a javascript expert, often has some interesting links and blog posts.

Answer (score 3):

For anything .NET you cant go past Scott Gu's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/).

Answer (score 3):

[DZone](http://www.dzone.com) is pretty good if you want to know what's happening in programmer blogosphere, especially for Java programmers, but not limited to Java. The thing I like the most about them is monthly e-mail newsletter with top links for the month, which makes me return, especially if I didn't have much time to procrastrinate that month.

Comment: +1. Dzone.com is becoming a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of the recommended blogs if you're into .NET development:

- http://haacked.com
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/
- http://www.nikhilk.net

Answer (score 2):

For PHP-related stuff [PHP Planet](http://www.planet-php.net/) and for PostgreSQL [Planet PostgreSQL](http://www.planetpostgresql.org/). If you're intrested in PostgreSQL [depesz](http://www.depesz.com/) has a very nice blog with a lot of information about upcoming versions, performance tweaks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Ayende](http://ayende.com)'s (creator of [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)) blog is a great read.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to mention www.codeproject.com is good one to get latest news too.

Answer (score 1):

Check also: http://www.infoq.com/

Answer (score 1):

I find a lot of helpfull info at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetkicks.com (dnk)

dnk is a .net focussed community site, a kick being a .net digg is you wish, and in some part may well have inspired some ideas on the admirable stackoverflow.

Some of the blogs above are excellent and I subscribe to many of them, but for what is latest updates, it is hard to beat dnk for it aggregation and collective ranking.  You will find all of the above there but also some very interesting one blog wonders as well.